# How to restrict date and month not valid in Jquery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```js
//Put our input DOM element into a jQuery Object
var $jqDate = jQuery('input[name="jqueryDate"]');

//Bind keyup/keydown to the input
$jqDate.bind('keyup','keydown', function(e){
 
  //To accomdate for backspacing, we detect which key was pressed - if backspace, do nothing:
 if(e.which !== 8) { 
  var numChars = $jqDate.val().length;
  if(numChars === 2 || numChars === 5){
   var thisVal = $jqDate.val();
   thisVal += '/';
   $jqDate.val(thisVal);
  }
  }
});
```

```html
<div style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 150%;">
  <strong>HTML5 "date" input type:</strong> <input type="date" name="html5date"><br>
  <strong>jQuery "date" input type mimic:</strong> <input type="text" name="jqueryDate" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><br>
  Key Input: <span id="keyP">null</span>
</div>
```

In the above code i have a textbox . In that textbox user enter date manually . It takes date format worked . But user enter day more than 31 and month 12 it not accept.How to restrict date and month by using Jquery or Javascript.

This is Jsfiddle :-   https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisCoray/hLkjhsce/

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: i enter 45/40/2016

Comment: Please show your attempts to solve the problem.

Comment: use bootstrap and jquery datepicker not need to check it manually, those data picker will handle it automatically

Answer (score 0):

You Need to add 'datePicker'as  class name

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'd/mm/yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: Date.parse("1900-01-01"),
        maxDate: Date.parse("2100-01-01"),
        yearRange: "c-90:c+150"
    });

    // validation in case user types the date out of valid range from keyboard : To fix the bug with out of range date time while saving in sql 
    $(function () {
        $.validator.addMethod(
            "date",
            function (value, element) {

                var minDate = Date.parse("1900-01-01");
                var maxDate = Date.parse("2100-01-01");
                var valueEntered = Date.parse(value);

                if (valueEntered < minDate || valueEntered > maxDate) {
                    return false;
                }
                return !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(minDate));
            },
            "Please enter a valid date!"
        );
    });
```